# getting a value from user control

Tags: asp.net

I have an issue that i believe there is a simple solution for but being new to ASP.NET it is not very clear to me.

I have a user control that has a for loop that makes bunch of hyperlink elements in a list (looks like below>

```
<li><a href="blahblah.aspx?ID=1..../></li>
<li><a href="blahblah.aspx?ID=2..../></li>
<li><a href="blahblah.aspx?ID=3..../></li>
<li><a href="blahblah.aspx?ID=4..../></li>
```

Next, that uc is used in another page with in a `<form>` tag with `method="post"` and `<asp:button>` that isn't really used.

Next, when one of the links is clicked it will go to blahblah.asp and get the ID in there via `Request.QueryString`

So far so good.

What i want to do though (and the reason for this post) is that i want to not use ID as a query parameter.  I want to pass the ID in the body.  So the link would be blahblah.aspx and it wouldn't show the ID.

What would be the best way to accomplish this.  I've tried couple different ways but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this will work for you, but instead of using html a tags, use the asp LinkButton control. You can then handle the command event of this control so have your for loop generate the following controls (or better yet use a repeater):

```
<asp:LinkButton id="button1" runat="server" CommandArgument="1" OnCommand="SendToBlah" />
<asp:LinkButton id="button2" runat="server" CommandArgument="2" OnCommand="SendToBlah" />

private void SendToBlah(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    Session["ID"] = e.CommandArgument;
    Response.Redirect("blahblah.aspx");
}
```

You can then use your session argument inside your blahblah.aspx page however you see fit.

Comment: This does work but everything is hardcoded. Since I'm in `for` loop, if i try to set linkbutton's ID with `ID="button<%=j%>"` it doesn't work

Comment: Since i'm in a framed window is it possible to open blahblah.aspx in another frame? or will it always open in the same frame.  I don't see 'target' attribute in linkbutton like there is in anchor

Comment: @user2844121 you can use the for loop in a server side script to add the link button controls to a server side panel or div. To answer your second question the method I provided redirects the user so they would not be able to open it in a new tab.

Comment: but, as i mentioned above, if i try to use the for loop to make dynamic controls in the div it doesn't work for example `<asp:LinkButton ID="button<%=j%>"...../>` doesn't work.

Comment: @user2844121 take a look at this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyt0fzt1(VS.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks, i figured it out right after i asked this.  Should of deleted it

Answer (score 0):

To send the data in the HTTP body instead of the query string, you need to do an HTTP post.  This is easy enough, just use a form with a hidden parameter:

```
<li>
    <form action="blahblah.aspx" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="1" />
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
</li>
```

To get the data on the target page, use `Request.Params` instead of QueryString.

Now, if you want to use a hyperlink rather than a "submit" button, you can always submit the form using Javascript:

```
<li>
    <form id="myform1" action="blahblah.aspx" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="1" />
    </form>
    <a href="#" onclick="submitForm('myform1')">Submit the form</a>

    <form id="myform2" action="blahblah.aspx" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="1" />
    </form>
    <a href="#" onclick="submitForm('myform2')">Submit the form</a>
</li>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    window.submitForm = function(id) {
        document.forms[id].submit();
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This was a first thing i tried but i ran into a problem.  The page with <li>s is a .ascx it is just a uc.  There is another page that uses the uc. If I have a form in this page and then a form on the other page that uses the uc i get a run time error

Comment: @user2844121 the runtime error should only be if both forms have `runat="server"`.  Remove that from these ones and you should be ok...?

Comment: it says "Object doesn't support property or method 'submit' ".  In the javascript line you have.  Could it be because it is in `for` loop and so it has lots of forms with same name?

Comment: @user2844121 I forgot that you have multiple forms -- maybe that's why?  You would have to specify a unique ID for each form (updated above).

Comment: @user2844121 make sure to get the index inside the quotes (no `+`): id="myform<%=j%>".  Also, it needs to be in the parameter: `onclick="submitForm('myform<%=j%>')"`

Comment: He is using asp.net webforms which only allows 1 form on the page

Comment: @Vadim we discussed that above in the comments.  Multiple forms are ok, as long as only one of them has `runat="server"`.